# Filtering grid view when binded using datasender in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have a gridview to which values are loaded by stored procedure.  the grid view is binded to the data source in the aspx.cs file. Now i need to place a filter option for the grid view in aspx page based on the fields in the grid view.

any one please help me out, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataView and filter the GridView data:

//filter Gridview ---- doesn't filter

```
    DataView dv = new DataView();
    dv.RowFilter = "ColumnName = '" + txt.Text.ToString() + "'";
    GridViewID.DataSource = dv;
    GridViewID.DataBind();
```